# wowslider doesn't work properly after hosting the website

Tags: jquery, web, responsive-slides, website-hosting, wowslider

I added a wowslider to my home page. It worked perfectly in my local server (viewed on google chrome [v 55.0.2883.87 m] and safari [v 5.1.7]). However, after hosting it on a live server, i'm having issues with the height of the slider in google chrome. Im not sure why this is happening. Please help! How can i fix this?

This is my site url:
https://feathertest.000webhostapp.com/index.php

This is a screenshot of how it looks in my local server:
[image: website on local server]

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two import of jquery by "" tag in your page , try to remove the last one in your page and place the other declaration in the top after  for example.

and in your CSS, replace the max-height of the class  #wowslider-container1 by height.